# Writing human readable data to XML file without success

Tags: php, xml

I have been through this about 3 hours without success. Can someone point me out what is wrong with the script? It writes the information but it does in one line, I am formating it, tried in different ways and nothing it just keeps in one line.

```
<?php
if (!file_exists ($fpath))
    {
        $fo = fopen($fpath, 'a') or die("Failed to create file.");
        fwrite($fo, "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\r<".$fname.">\r</".$fname.">") or die("Failed to format file.");
        fclose($fo);
    }

    $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $xml->formatOutput = true;
    $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $xml->load($fpath);

    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    @$email = $_POST['email'];

    $nonode = $xml->getElementsByTagName($sn);

    if ($nonode->length == 0)
    {
        $addnode = $xml->createElement($sn);
        $newnode = $addnode->appendChild($xml->createElement('data'));
        $newnode->appendChild($xml->createElement('date', $date));

        if (isset ($_POST['email']))
        {
            $newnode->appendChild($xml->createElement('email', $email));
        }

        $xml->getElementsByTagName($fname)->item(0)->appendChild($addnode);
        $xml->save($fpath);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Does anything different happen if you set `$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = true;` ?

Comment: No, it keeps doing the same. Thanks @Ken H.

Comment: Why are you delimiting lines with `\r` (carriage return) in the original string? Shouldn't it be `\n` (newline)?

Comment: Well, in the beginning I was using `/n` but later changed it to `/r` trying to go around the problem, both do the work except if data is written when creating the file
Thanks @Jim Garrison

Answer (score 2):

Playing around with it, got it working as wanted. Replacing `fopen()`, `fwrite` when checking if `file_exists()` with the creation of the XML elements, the resulting script looks like this:

```
<?php
if (!file_exists ($fpath))
    {
        $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
        $xml->formatOutput = true;
        $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

        $rootnode = $xml->createElement($fname);
        $addnode = $rootnode->appendChild($xml->createElement($sn));
        $newnode = $addnode->appendChild($xml->createElement('data'));

        if (isset ($_POST['email']))
        {
            $newnode->appendChild($xml->createElement('email', $email));
        }

        $xml->appendChild($rootnode);
        $xml->save($fpath);
    }
?>
```

Output a pretty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<expdb>
  <sn>
    <data>
      <email>myemail@email.com</email>
    </data>
  </sn>
</expdb>
```

Thanks to all and hope this could help someone. You should take this as a reference, *note the XML tags names and XML function arguments*.